# HTML Replace Select item with something more formatable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have on a website a select box to select the language of the website:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<select class="w3-bar-item w3-select w3-right w3-button" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value" style="-webkit-appearance: none;">
    <option value="?&lang=lu"<?php if ($_SESSION['lang'] == "lu") echo "selected='selected'";?>>Lëtzebuergesch</option>
    <option value="?&lang=en"<?php if ($_SESSION['lang'] == "en") echo "selected='selected'";?>>English</option>
    <option value="?&lang=fr"<?php if ($_SESSION['lang'] == "fr") echo "selected='selected'";?>>Français</option>
    <option value="?&lang=de"<?php if ($_SESSION['lang'] == "de") echo "selected='selected'";?>>Deutsch</option>
</select>
```

This works all fine but I cannot format it as i want. I would like to replace it with something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

    <div class="w3-dropdown-hover">
      <button class="w3-button">Dropdown</button>
      <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lëtzebuergesch</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">English</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Français</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Deutsch</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So that when you chose the language it sets the value of &lang and sets the name of the button to the language that is selected.

I hope someone can help me with this.

You can see the select box in action here on the upper right of the site:
(https://elgaucho.lu/beta/)

Thanks for your help

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll a bit to see how to make a custom select. All you need are last HTML and CSS codes. Other codes are just to implement the logic with JS (I know you did that with PHP).

**Standard HTML select solution.**

HTML:

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="?&lang=lu">Lëtzebuergesch</option>
    <option value="?&lang=en">English</option>
    <option value="?&lang=fr">Français</option>
    <option value="?&lang=de">Deutsch</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const select = document.getElementById('select');
    select.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if (this.value) {
            location.href = this.value;
        }
    });

    // loop through select options
    // and if page URL contains option value, select it
    for (let i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
        if (location.href.includes(select.options[i].value)) {
            select.value = select.options[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

**Custom select solution:**

HTML:

```
<div id="my-select">
    <div id="my-select-label">Lëtzebuergesch</div>
    <div id="my-select-options">
        <div data-value="?&lang=lu">Lëtzebuergesch</div>
        <div data-value="?&lang=en">English</div>
        <div data-value="?&lang=fr">Français</div>
        <div data-value="?&lang=de">Deutsch</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#my-select {
    width: 150px;
}
#my-select:hover #my-select-options {
    display: block;
}
#my-select-options {
    display: none;
}
#my-select-options > div {
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top: none;
}
#my-select-label {
    margin-top: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const mySelectLabel = document.getElementById('my-select-label');
    const mySelectOptions = document.querySelectorAll('#my-select-options > div');
    for (let i = 0; i < mySelectOptions.length; i++) {
        mySelectOptions[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            location.href = this.getAttribute('data-value');
        });
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < mySelectOptions.length; i++) {
        if (location.href.includes(mySelectOptions[i].getAttribute('data-value'))) {
            mySelectLabel.textContent = mySelectOptions[i].textContent;
            break;
        }
        mySelectLabel.textContent = mySelectOptions[0].textContent;
    }
});
```

If you have any questions, ask.

Comment: Thanks @Michael . This helped me to find a solution in php.